# Backbone.js render called before content is fetched

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I found an example of some Backbone.js code that I then adopted to my needs.

The `render` function of `CommentListView` is called before any content is fetched. It seems that it not called again when there are content to render.

The backend returns two results, so that is not the problem.

```
// Models
window.Comment = Backbone.Model.extend();

window.CommentCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Comment,
    url:"/api/comments/cosmopolitan"
});


// Views
window.CommentListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName:'ul',

    initialize:function () {
        this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    },

    render:function (eventName) {
        console.log(this.model.models);
        _.each(this.model.models, function (comment) {
            console.log(comment);
            $(this.el).append(new CommentListItemView({model:comment}).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }

});

window.CommentListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName:"li",

    template:_.template($('#tpl-comment-list-item').html()),

    render:function (eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }

});

// Router
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes:{
        "":"list"
    },

    list:function () {
        this.commentList = new CommentCollection();
        this.commentListView = new CommentListView({model:this.commentList});
        this.commentList.fetch();

        $('#sidebar').html(this.commentListView.render().el);
    }
});

var app = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
```

Comment: Backbone version 1.0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior of `fetch` has changed a bit in Backbone 1.0.0. From the [ChangeLog](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog):

> - Renamed Collection's "update" to *set*, for parallelism with the similar `model.set()`, and contrast with *reset*. It's now the default updating mechanism after a *fetch*. If you'd like to continue using "reset", pass `{reset: true}`.

And [`Collection#fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) says:

> **fetch** `collection.fetch([options])`
>
> Fetch the default set of models for this collection from the server, *setting* them on the collection when they arrive. [...] When the model data returns from the server, it uses *set* to (intelligently) merge the fetched models, unless you pass `{reset: true}`,

Your `initialize` just binds to `"reset"`:

```
this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
```

You can either bind to the `"add"`, `"remove"`, and `"change"` events that [`Collection#set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-set) will generate or you can explicitly ask for a `"reset"` event when you `fetch`:

```
this.commentList.fetch({ reset: true });
```

A couple other things while I'm here:

1. Since your `CommentListView` view is using a collection rather than a model, you might want to call it `collection`:

   ```
   this.commentListView = new CommentListView({collection: this.commentList});
   ```

   and then refer to `this.collection` inside the view. See [`View#initialize`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor) for details on how view constructors handle their arguments.
2. Collections have various [Underscore methods mixed in](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) so you can say `this.collection.each(function(model) { ... })` instead of `_.each(this.model.models, ...)`.
3. Views maintain a cached version of the jQuery-wrapped `el` in [`$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el) so you can say `this.$el` instead of `$(this.el)`.
4. Be careful with things like `console.log(this.model.models)`. The console usually grabs a live reference so what shows up in the console will be the state of `this.model.models` when you look rather than when `console.log` is called. Using `console.log(this.model.toJSON())` is more reliable when faced with timing and AJAX issues.
5. You might want to switch to [`listenTo`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) instead of [`bind`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on) (AKA `on`) as that is less susceptible to memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks a lot - both for the solution (binding to add, remove and change worked), and for providing the general advice.

Answer (score 0):

Usually is use to create a listener for the fetch, when fetch is complete and change the model or collection there is a callback. try this:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes:{
        "":"list"
    },

    list:function () {
        this.commentList = new CommentCollection();
        this.commentListView = new CommentListView({model:this.commentList});
        this.listenTo(this.commentList,'change', this.makeRender);
        this.commentList.fetch();


    },
    makeRender: function(){
        $('#sidebar').html(this.commentListView.render().el);
   }

});
```

Comment: I modified the code, and added some console.log stagements to debug (code: http://pastebin.com/eQn2uUE6) - output: CommentListView:initialize - AppRouter:list done - i.e. makeRender is never called even though the AJAX request completes successfully.